# How do group elements in an array of objects of different sizes by comparing two different unique properties? in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, lodash

I have two different array of objects that i get from an aggregate function because I am using two different collections.

I have tried using the map function like discribed here, but it does not solve my problem what else can i do to get the desired results?

```
  qrySearch = [{
    sName: 'SomePlace1',
    lBusinessID: 37343,
    SystemID: 5000152
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace2',
    lBusinessID: 39780,
    SystemID: 5000156
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace3',
    lBusinessID: 50772,
    SystemID: 5000519
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace4',
    lBusinessID: 31079,
    SystemID: 5000384
  }
]
```

and

```
qrySearchLocID = [{
    LocalLabID: '123f',
    _ID: 'SomePlace1',
    AppLabID: 3,
    count: 15   
  },
  {
    LocalLabID: '12BC',
    _ID: 'SomePlace2',
    AppLabID: 3,
    count: 40
  }
];
```

after trying the result is only this array :

```
qrySearch = [{
    sName: 'SomePlace1',
    lBusinessID: 37343,
    SystemID: 5000152
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace2',
    lBusinessID: 39780,
    SystemID: 5000156
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace3',
    lBusinessID: 50772,
    SystemID: 5000519
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace4',
    lBusinessID: 31079,
    SystemID: 5000384
  },
]
```

for simplicity ive kept the array short. I need to compare the _ID if it matches sName for desired output:

```
result = [{
        sName: 'SomePlace1',
        lBusinessID: 37343,
        SystemID: 5000152,
        LocalLabID: '123f',
        AppLabID: 3,
        count: 15
      },
      {
        sName: 'SomePlace2',
        lBusinessID: 39780,
        SystemID: 5000156,
        LocalLabID: '12BC',
        AppLabID: 3,
        count: 40
      },
      {
        sName: 'SomePlace3',
        lBusinessID: 50772,
        SystemID: 5000519
      },
      {
        sName: 'SomePlace4',
        lBusinessID: 31079,
        SystemID: 5000384
      }
    ]
```

I've tried using this example:

```
var result = qrySearch.map((e, _) => 
          (_ = qrySearchLocID.find((q) => q._ID=== e.sName)) ? 
          { ...e, ...{ _ID: _._ID} } : e);
```

but the count is missing from results.

Comment: After trying the result is only the qrySearch array. on console.log output the qrySearchLocID array does not even display on the console

Comment: _"After trying the result is only the qrySearch array. on console.log output the qrySearchLocID array does not even display on the console"_ Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can just spread your placeholder `_` too to merge the values

```js
const qrySearch = [{
    sName: 'SomePlace1',
    lBusinessID: 37343,
    SystemID: 5000152
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace2',
    lBusinessID: 39780,
    SystemID: 5000156
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace3',
    lBusinessID: 50772,
    SystemID: 5000519
  },
  {
    sName: 'SomePlace4',
    lBusinessID: 31079,
    SystemID: 5000384
  },
];

const qrySearchLocID = [{
    LocalLabID: '123f',
    _ID: 'SomePlace1',
    AppLabID: 3,
    count: 15


  },
  {
    LocalLabID: '12BC',
    _ID: 'SomePlace2',
    AppLabID: 3,
    count: 40
  },
];

var res = qrySearch.map((e, _) => 
          (_ = qrySearchLocID.find((q) => q._ID=== e.sName)) ? 
          { ...e, ..._ }: e);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: hmm ok..I have some of the result displaying the desired output,  but some are missing the count even though the _ID and sName matches

Comment: The ones that dont link up wont have counts. This code produces your desired outcome as per your post

Answer (score 0):

Create a flow that concats the two arrays, groups them by `sName` or `_ID`, and maps all groups to a new merged object:

```js
const { flow, concat, groupBy, map, merge, partialRight: pr } = _;

const combine = flow(
  concat,
  pr(groupBy, o => o.sName || o._ID),
  pr(map, g => merge({}, ...g))
);

const qrySearch = [{"sName":"SomePlace1","lBusinessID":37343,"SystemID":5000152},{"sName":"SomePlace2","lBusinessID":39780,"SystemID":5000156},{"sName":"SomePlace3","lBusinessID":50772,"SystemID":5000519},{"sName":"SomePlace4","lBusinessID":31079,"SystemID":5000384}];

const qrySearchLocID = [{"LocalLabID":"123f","_ID":"SomePlace1","AppLabID":3,"count":15},{"LocalLabID":"12BC","_ID":"SomePlace2","AppLabID":3,"count":40}];

const result = combine(qrySearch, qrySearchLocID);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And the same idea using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
const { flow, concat, groupBy, map, mergeAll, propOr } = _;

const combine = flow(
  concat,
  groupBy(o => o.sName || o._ID),
  map(mergeAll)
);

const qrySearch = [{"sName":"SomePlace1","lBusinessID":37343,"SystemID":5000152},{"sName":"SomePlace2","lBusinessID":39780,"SystemID":5000156},{"sName":"SomePlace3","lBusinessID":50772,"SystemID":5000519},{"sName":"SomePlace4","lBusinessID":31079,"SystemID":5000384}];

const qrySearchLocID = [{"LocalLabID":"123f","_ID":"SomePlace1","AppLabID":3,"count":15},{"LocalLabID":"12BC","_ID":"SomePlace2","AppLabID":3,"count":40}];

const result = combine(qrySearch, qrySearchLocID);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```